# How to change inner div's when cloning a template?

Tags: javascript, clone

I have a template that I'm cloning to make Single Page Application. Inside this template are some div's that should have a unique id's so that it should be working individually when I open multiple apps(clone multiple divs)

```
<template id="templ">
<div id="name"></div>
<div id="btn"> 
  <fieldset id="fld">
  <input type="text" id="userMessage"placeholder="Type your message…"   autofocus>
  <input type="hidden">
  <button id="send" >Save</button>
  </fieldset>
 </div>
</template>
```

and I'm cloning it like this

```
 var i =0
let template = document.querySelector('#templ')
let clone = document.importNode(template.content, true)
clone.id = 'name' + ++i // I can't change the Id o this name div
document.querySelector('body').appendChild(clone)
```

Thanks

Comment: put `++i` between **( )**

Comment: it works without putting it into brackets, because of the space, not a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clone.id` is undefined since clone is a `#document-fragment` with two children.

You need to query the 'name' child and change its id, for example like this:

```
const template = document.querySelector('#templ')
const body = document.querySelector('body')

function appendClone(index){
    let clone = document.importNode(template.content, true)
    clone.getElementById('name').id = 'name' + index
    // all other elements with IDs
    body.appendChild(clone)
}
```

Then you can iterate over the amount of clones and simply call the function with the loop index:

```
let clones = 5
for (let i = 0; i < clones; i++){
    appendClone(i)
}
```

Comment: This will not work if I have say 5 clones. All 'name' children will have the same id

Comment: Then you will of course have to iterate over the clones, but my answer stays valid. I can add an example function later as soon as I'm home. Also, remember that you will have to change every id.

Answer (score 0):

store the dynamic HTML data in script element and add when ever required by replaciing with dynamic data.

HTML Data:

```
<script id="hidden-template" type="text/x-custom-template">
    <div id='${dynamicid}'>
        <p>${dynamic_data}</p>
    </div>
</script>
```

Script to replace and append.

```
var template_add = $('#hidden-template').text();
var items = [{
    dynamicid: '1',
    dynamic_data: '0'
    }];

function replaceDynamicData(props) {
    return function(tok, i) {
        return (i % 2) ? props[tok] : tok;
    };
}
var dynamic_HTML = template_add.split(/\$\{(.+?)\}/g);
$('tbody').append(items.map(function(item) {
    return dynamic_HTML.map(replaceDynamicData(item)).join('');
}));
```